# Most efficient way to communicate with my Router via Telnet

Tags: c#, network-programming, telnet

I have a Thomson ADSL router that offers a telnet interface.
In order to config it, I am using windows Telnet command line.

The communication is "Request -> Results" based.
eg. "modem do this", "ok i just did"

What I want to do is create an application that does this automatically.
For example to be able to set a list of commands to be sent to the router.

How can I do such a communication using C#?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053468/how-can-i-open-a-telnet-connection-and-run-a-few-commands-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Use a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28VS.71%29.aspx) and wrap the stream with a StreamReader / StreamWriter.